# Why django does not create an app as a subfolder?

Tags: python, django, pip

I run into problem of creating an app in python, django framework.
Before, in command promt, I run

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7\py manage.py runserver
```

which works perfectly, after that I run

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7\py manage.py startapp myapp
```

and it does not create any folder "webapp" at all. Please, help.
My OS is Windows 10, Python version 2.7.8, Django version 2.1.3, pip version 10.0.1

Also, when running `pip install -U django` 
 getting `Requirement already up-to-date`

When running `django-admin.py startapp myapp`   getting `Permission denied`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are running it in a folder where you don't have write permission. Either Use the command prompt in admin mode or use a folder in which you have write access . to check this, just try to create a text file. if you are able to , then it means you have write access. My Guess on why it worked before is that you ran it in a command prompt which is in admin mode

Comment: yes, I can create a txt file. Also I run the command exactly after the first one so admin mode is not changed.

Comment: @Liana , can you post the complete traceback

Comment: Solved simply by restarting the terminal and pc. Old method never dies.